# No compatible target found do you wish to add a new android virtual devide

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have installed eclipse and android sdk and I create project in eclipse when I run my projects, then little window pop up title android avd error and the text written on it like 
no compatible target found do you wish to add a new android virtual devide

```
[2012-08-24 07:56:59 - The basics] ------------------------------<br/>
[2012-08-24 07:56:59 - The basics] Android Launch!<br/>
[2012-08-24 07:56:59 - The basics] adb is running normally.<br/>
[2012-08-24 07:56:59 - The basics] Performing com.adnanbhatti.com.MainActivity activity launch<br/>
[2012-08-24 07:56:59 - The basics] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 2.2'.<br/>
[2012-08-24 07:57:02 - The basics] Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Android 2.2': Aborting launch.<br/>
[2012-08-24 07:57:02 - The basics] Performing com.adnanbhatti.com.MainActivity activity launch<br/>
[2012-08-24 07:57:07 - The basics] Launch canceled!<br/>
[2012-08-24 08:41:10 - The basics] ------------------------------<br/>
[2012-08-24 08:41:10 - The basics] Android Launch!<br/>
[2012-08-24 08:41:10 - The basics] adb is running normally.<br/>
[2012-08-24 08:41:10 - The basics] Performing com.adnanbhatti.com.MainActivity activity launch<br/>
[2012-08-24 08:41:10 - The basics] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 2.2'.<br/>
[2012-08-24 08:44:18 - The basics] Performing com.adnanbhatti.com.MainActivity activity launch<br/>
[2012-08-24 08:44:19 - The basics] Launch canceled!
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have related Emulator to run the application, create avd with your application android version..

Answer (score 1):

You must create the emulator via  `WINDOWS > AVD MANAGER > THEN SELECT A NEW` ,Now you can create AVD as per your choice target.

And also add into `manifest` file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create emulator target via AVD or attach real device to run compiled application.

Answer (score 0):

Create your emulator with AVD Manager and also check your application's  minSdkVersion like this: `android:minSdkVersion="8"` for an example my app targets with Android 2.2 which is having an api level 8. So create emulator targeting Android 2.3.